# Repacking initrd.img with SSH keys

Tags: ssh, initramfs

So I'm trying to modify `initrd.img` which is used on Raspberry Pi 2(Ubuntu 18.04) but when I repack it again and start Raspberry Pi with new initrd.img I can't connect via SSH(**dropbear** is installed) to enter passphrase for unlocking LUKS encrypted drive: `Permission denied (publickey).`Same situation when I don't make any changes: just extracting initrd.img and repacking it again - can't connect via SSH. I'm getting almost same file size after repacking comparing with original file(difference is around ~1-2KB). So maybe my repacking method is wrong or maybe there is some protection for SSH keys inside initramfs?

Commands that I used for **extraction**:

`gzip -dc < ~/initrd.img | cpio -i`

**Repacking**:

`find . | cpio -H newc -o | gzip -9 > ~/initrdNEW.img`

## EDIT

After extracting initrd.img there is `root-sJD1OZ/.ssh/` directory with `authorized_keys` file inside it. When I `update-initramfs` on my Rasperry Pi and then extract contents again, that directory name changes(e.g. `root-XXXXXX`).

If you have any questions, please ask.